# Correct way to declare for handsets only in manifest

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

After searching the many old answers on stack overflow about this subject and not finding a definite updated answer i am still a bit confused! my minSdk is 14 and want to make my app for handsets only however if i do this

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
```

What about phones like the galaxy s4 s5 s6 and s6 edge! would they not fall into the large category? and if so how would this be declared without opening support for the tablets?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringHandsetApps

Comment: not very helpful, as you can see i have pasted the same code from that link in my question and that still does not answer the question

Comment: yes i got it that it's not helpful, just posted the official docs links in comment for adding it to the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<compatible-screens>
        <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="640" android:screenSize="small" />

        <screen android:screenDensity="ldpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="mdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="hdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="xhdpi" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen android:screenDensity="640" android:screenSize="normal" />
    </compatible-screens>
```

I got supported android density values from https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html (Range of screens supported)

but I'm not sure that it will work for Sony Xperia Z5 Premium, because its density 801dp (http://dpi.lv/#3840×2160@5.5″)

Comment: would this include devices such as the s4 s5 s6 s7

Comment: Yes, it's include this devices

Comment: will try this, however to test it i would need to put apk on google play store

Comment: Yes, I know, I had the same problem and this solution worked for me

Comment: Do you tested my solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following in my code and it works just fine in Google Play.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true" />
```